# Xbox 360 Steering Wheel on Xbox One

Tags: pc, xbox-360, xbox-one, windows-10, streaming

I recently decided to start playing racing games again but of course my old 360 steering wheel won't connect to my Xbox One.

Found out there was a work around by streaming through windows 10 so I tried that but getting weird bugs. The steering wheel (controller) is calibrated with windows 10 and inputs seem fine when testing but as soon as I start streaming the controller starts acting funny.

It appears as if the left directional arrow is constantly pressed even though this didn't happen in windows test. I ma able to use the up and down arrows on controller but none of the other buttons. Feel it may be a mapping issue but can't seem to find anywhere on the Xbox companion app to reconfigure.

Any ideas?